# Forked Parity pallet, didn't migrate storage, deployed to chain. How to clear original storage from the live chain?

Tags: pallet, storage, migration, cleanup, fork

We started a chain using pallet_collator_selection and later forked it.
Both the original and the forked pallet use the `LastAuthoredBlock` StorageItem.
We did **not** execute a storage migration from the original to the forked pallet.

[The storage docs](https://docs.substrate.io/v3/advanced/storage/#storage-value-keys) state that a storage key is made up of the `pallet name` and the `item name`, implying that our forked pallet actually created its own storage key `hash(forked_collator_selection)hash(LastAuthoredBlock)` instead of reusing `hash(pallet_collator_selection)hash(LastAuthoredBlock)`, rendering the latter unused memory.

**Is there a way to free the memory of the old, now unreferenced `hash(pallet_collator_selection)hash(LastAuthoredBlock)` StorageItem on the live chain after the forked pallet has been deployed without migrating storage at the time?**

Corollary question to: [Reclaim used space of a removed StorageItem on a live chain](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/504/reclaim-used-space-of-a-removed-storageitem-on-a-live-chain)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [remove_storage_prefix](https://docs.rs/frame-support/latest/frame_support/storage/migration/fn.remove_storage_prefix.html):

```
remove_storage_prefix("OldPalletNameInYourRuntime", "LastAuthoredBlock", &[]);
```

You need to place this into a runtime migration. The last parameter `hash` is empty here because you don't have a map here (the function is generic over storage items and maps).

Or you could also send a transaction to your chain [`kill_storage`](https://docs.rs/frame-system/latest/frame_system/pallet/enum.Call.html#variant.kill_storage). Be aware that this call requires `root`. As argument you pass a vector with the only element being the raw key of the old storage item (`hash(pallet_collator_selection)hash(LastAuthoredBlock)`).